# Installing pygraphviz on Windows 7 x64 for Python 3.5 x32 failing with fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: python, pygraphviz

I have read as much as I could about thjis but I am stuck and am not making any progress. I have tried to apply a patch as recommended in on the threads around here but that failed.
I am installing from source, downloaded from Github

Here is my command line

```
c:\Users\MyName\Downloads\pygraphviz\pygraphviz-master>C:\Users\MyName\AppData\L
ocal\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe setup.py install --include-path "C:
Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\include" --library-path "C:\Program Files (x86)
\Graphviz2.38\lib\release\lib"
```

I am getting this error

......

```
graphviz_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PyIOBase_Type
build\lib.win32-3.5\pygraphviz\_graphviz.cp35-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1
 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\
link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Could anybody please please help me with this? I would hate to have to use a different python library for my application

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I abandoned this idea. Probably the way to do it can be learned from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571067/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362845/714413