# Pygraphviz Windows 10 import error: No module named '_graphviz'

Tags: python, windows, graphviz, pygraphviz

I installed pygraphviz by following the instruction here: [Installing pygraphviz on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571067/installing-pygraphviz-on-windows)

I am getting an import error while importing pygraphviz: I do have graphviz installed in my system

> > > import pygraphviz
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\Prajnan_Goswami\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\graphviz.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
> > >           fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_graphviz', [dirname(**file**)])
> > >         File "C:\Users\Prajnan_Goswami\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
> > >           raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
> > >       ImportError: No module named '_graphviz'

Could someone tell me if I am missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add graphviz to your PATH so that it can correctly locate the module.