# NetworkX read_dot does not inherit attributes

Tags: python, networkx, decision-tree

I'm trying to read a .dot file produced by sklearn.tree.export_to_graphviz into a graph using NetworkX. I plan to add this graph as a subplot in a pyplot graph. While I'm able to use nx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot to obtain the graph structure, all of the labels seem to disappear.

This is what I'm trying:

```
randTree = (nx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot("tree_output.dot"))
nx.draw_networkx(randTree)
```

The .dot file is:

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box] ;
0 [label="X[0] <= 332.72\nsamples = 19\nvalue = -0.41"] ;
1 [label="samples = 11\nvalue = -0.67"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="X[0] <= 576.73\nsamples = 8\nvalue = -0.04"] ;
0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
3 [label="samples = 4\nvalue = -0.05"] ;
2 -> 3 ;
4 [label="samples = 4\nvalue = -0.03"] ;
2 -> 4 ;
}
```

What results is a graph with 4 circles labeled 1-4, without any other labels or properties (I imagine the box shape is a property of the node so that's why they're all circles), which is linked below. If there is another way to show this decision in a pyplot plot, I'd be happy to hear!

[Resulting Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDd1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue isn't with `nx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot`, but with drawing the network.
When reading the dot file the labels are kept, however you'll need to use NetworkX' [drawing API](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) a bit differently to draw the labels. For example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ast

randTree = (nx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot('tree_output.dot'))
labels = {n[0] : ast.literal_eval(n[1]['label']) for n in randTree.nodes(data=True)}
nx.draw_networkx(randTree, with_labels=True, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

Will draw:

[image]

**Edit:**

You can also convert the graph to a [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org) `AGraph` and draw it as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

A = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.to_agraph(nx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot('tree_output.dot'))
A.layout('dot')
A.draw('tree.png')
```

Which will draw the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to take all of the properties (such as the box shape and the edge labels) from the .dot file and insert them into the NetworkX graph at the same time? Or is it a matter of pulling everything out feature by feature?

Comment: I thought you want to show your graph with matplotlib pyplot, and then you would have to convert it feature by feature (I've shown how to extract labels, positioning of nodes can be done with **layouts**, nodes' shape with **node_shape** parameter etc.). I edited the original answer to show how to visualize the graph with all graphviz properties from the input dot file. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Windows which apparently isn't playing nice with pygraphviz so I can't take that solution which is ultimately what I'm trying to achieve  :(

Comment: It can work on windows, maybe take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4571067/3782865