# Python 2.7 scapy install for windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, scapy

I am looking for scapy for windows on python 2.7. I have tried to download from thier official web: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows but it seems that the download link is not working [http://hg.secdev.org/scapy/archive/tip.zip]. It is just transfers me the main page of bitbucket.

I have also looked at: [Running Scapy on Windows with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447461/running-scapy-on-windows-with-python-2-7). I have tried to download the files from the first answers but the installation raises an error which says that I do not have python on my PC. Please, does anyone know where can I find download to scapy for python 2.7 on windows?

Answer (score 0):

They migrated the source code to github: https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Probably the equivalent link on github for master dev is: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip

Comment: Actually I downloaded that installation, it seems to work except the function sniff(): http://prntscr.com/dazgww I just figured that this installation is broken. So why sniff does not work?