# Sniff Function in Scapy not working Win

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, scapy, winpcap

I followed the instructions for installing Scapy for Python2.7 ([Running Scapy on Windows with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447461/running-scapy-on-windows-with-python-2-7)) on win64 however the sniff() function doesn't work and ends abruptly. What steps should I take in order to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those instructions are very outdated. You should remove both pycap and dnet. They are very old...

The latest dev scapy version (https://github.com/secdev/scapy) is much easier to install. Please follow the latest doc, which is very clear:

http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the device name:

```
IFACES.show() #--> will give you a table of your devices with an index
mydev = IFACES.dev_from_index(X)   #---> where X is the index of your desired interface
```

then do a sniff in scapy as shown:

```
sniff(iface=dev,prn=lambda x:x.summary)
```

Comment: This is correct. However scapy will select the used interface by default, so it is only required when having multiple networking interfaces