# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat even if there is in my computer

Tags: python, easy-install, hcluster

I am trying to install hcluster library [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hcluster) with easy_install but I have an error "error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

The problem is that if I search in my pc, the file is here "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC"

I google it but every site I found, send that they don't have the file at all.

Comment: Try running your script in Visual Studio's Command Prompt instead and not just from an ordinary launch of cmd.exe.

Comment: Just tried it with developer command prompt for VS2012 and I have the same error :(

Comment: I think you should examine your python script to see how it calls the batch file. And perhaps see as well if it considers the PATH variable.

Comment: On Windows, installing extensions that compile C code require that you have the same version of Visual Studio that was used to build the Python interpreter itself. You can use other C compilers, see [Building Python C extension modules for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101061/building-python-c-extension-modules-for-windows).